# How to delete document types in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I create an index "myindex" with a specified document type "mytype". I am able to delete the index, but it appears that "mytype" still exists without being tied to the index.

How do I get rid of "mytype"?

Comment: If you delete an index, the associated types are also deleted, they cannot exist without an index. What makes you think that "mytype" still exists ?

Comment: In the "head" plugin, I can go to "browser" and see that "mytype" is listed under "types"

Comment: Weird. A mapping belongs to a type and a type to an index. If you delete the index you lose them all. Are you sure you deleted the index using the delete API?

Comment: Yes, that's strange. Have you refreshed the page displaying the "head" plugin ? Sometimes it's needed to see the correct informations.

Comment: I deleted the index using the "Delete" option within the head application available under "Overview". I refreshed it just now and those "old" and "orphaned" types are still there...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you really deleted the index, the mapping in this index should not exist anymore.
Do you have any other index in your cluster with a similar type name?

To answer to the question: `How to delete document types in elasticsearch?`, use [Delete Mapping API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-delete-mapping/):

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index/type
```

**EDIT**: From elasticsearch 2.0, it won't be possible anymore. See [Mapping changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html). You will have to install the [Delete By Query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html) and run a query which will remove your documents but the mapping will still exist. So it will most likely better to reindex your documents in another index without the old type.

But as @mguillemin and @javanna said, when you delete an index, every mapping attached to this index is deleted as well:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/index
```

Comment: I'm able to do this via curl and sense but how can i delete a type using python client for elasticsearch, however I'm able to delete one document in a type using delete function.

Comment: the link to the delete by query plugin should be https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use `_delete_by_query` path to delete type.

```
POST index-name/type-name/_delete_by_query
{
    "query": { 
        "match": {
            "message": "some message"
        }
    }
}
```

For further reading see [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/docs-delete-by-query.html)

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of elastic search, they no longer support deleting document types. It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-mapping.html)

> It is no longer possible to delete the mapping for a type. Instead you
>   should delete the index and recreate it with the new mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to specify the request body. Just

```
curl -XPOST http://<host>:9200/<index>/<type>/_delete_by_query
```

Comment: It deletes documents but not mapping.

Comment: @expert https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-mapping.html

Comment: It doesn't work for version > 5.X. Response {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "exception",
        "reason": "_delete_by_query requires a request body"
      }
    ],
    "type": "exception",
    "reason": "_delete_by_query requires a request body"
  },
  "status": 500
}

Comment: The ES version is 5.3.2