# Delete records of a certain type from logstash/elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm about to embark upon importing a large number of records into elasticsearch (via logstash).

I'm sure I will make a few mistakes.  As such, I would like to be able to easily delete the imported records from elasticsearch.

For now, I can just delete the indicies containing the imports.  That only works because I won't have any other data on those same days.

In the future, I'd really like to query elasticsearch for all records of a certain type, and delete them.

In this case, the record type will be "nbu_job"

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546294/how-to-delete-document-types-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) to achieve that.

For instance, the following command will delete all documents of type `nbu_job` in the index `your_index`:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_query?q=_type:nbu_job'
```

If you need to verify what is going to be deleted with the above command, I suggest you run the query first so you can see what is matched with this command (note that `_query` endpoint becomes `_search` !)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_search?q=_type:nbu_job'
```

Note that if you do this, the mapping for `nbu_job` will still exist. So if you notice you've made errors in your mapping, you probably want to remove the `nbu_job` type altogether using

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/nbu_job'
```

Of course, `your_index` is whatever index name you need to work on, it can also be an [alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), a [comma-separated list of indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-multi-index-type) (e.g. `logstash-2015.06.11,logstash-2015.06.12`), an index wildcard (e.g. `logstash-*`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and I appreciate you giving me example code using my record type.  Can you explain the "your_index" component of this command ?  Based on my reading, I think there's an index created for each day ?  So would "your_index" be equal to something like "logstash-2015.06.11" ?    Also, can I also assume that by removing "-XDELETE" from the command, it defaults to a GET of some sort that I can use to pre-verify my delete ?

Comment: Yes, `your_index` was simply a placeholder for whatever index name you need to work on. It can also be an [`alias`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), or an index wildcard (e.g. `logstash-*`), it's pretty flexible. I'm updating my answer concerning your last comment.

Comment: Val, thanks for the quick response, and thanks for updating the question.  That will be really helpful to the next guy like me :)  I took your advice and deleted the entire "nbu_job" type via curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-*/nbu_job'.   Quick !  And sure enough, the KOPF plugin immediately registered the deletion of 300K records.   However, when I go back to Kibana and refresh the interface, it complains that "Courier Fetch: 75 of 95 shards failed".   Any way to clean that up ?

Comment: Did some googling.   Tried reloading my fields via the "Settings" tab within Kibana.   Didn't help.

Comment: Since you removed the `nbu_job` mapping type altogether, the mapping was also removed and Kibana probably didn't like it since it has some of its settings based on that type. My take is that you need to recreate the `nbu_job` mapping type after deleting it. It wil be empty, but it will be present at least.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Shortly after deleting the "nbu_job" type, I reloaded the same records (with slight modifications to my configuration to better import integer types, etc).   Less shards are now failing, but some still are. I'm not sure precisely what a shard is, but it feels like they get emptied out when I delete the nbu_job type (since that's the majority of data I have in this system at the moment).  No worries on this.  Other than the frequent messages, seems like no harm done.  Perhaps I'll post another question on this sub-topic later.  Will mark as answered.

Comment: [It just came out](https://www.elastic.co/blog/core-delete-by-query-is-a-plugin), but note that 1) the delete by query API has been moved to a plugin in ES 2.0 and 2) deleting a mapping type will not be possible anymore in ES 2.0. This means that this answer is good up to but not including ES 2.0.