# Elastic server type deletion

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index called libraries and many types inside it say customer , books and so on. Say i want to delete a type from the index is it possible? When i googled i found similar question asked in stack overflow [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546294/how-to-delete-document-types-in-elasticsearch)
in which a plugin Delete By Query plugin  is specified , but the URL is hitting 404. But its also mentioned its not possible. So if i want to delete data with mapping or data only of type customer , how can i achieve it?

If i maintain index for each type will it cause performance overhead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete document types in elasticsearch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546294/how-to-delete-document-types-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: As you yourself said this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546294/how-to-delete-document-types-in-elasticsearch . I fixed the broken link in the answer there.

Comment: Hi Daphna, the link still gives 404 :(. Hope this is the link you mentioned 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_removed_features.html#_delete_by_query_is_now_a_plugin

Comment: i found this URL, where its specified where we can delete data from type and also type itself
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-delete-by-query.html
but there $ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all/_query?q=tag:wow' . what is the tag:wow here means?